# Sharepoint 2013 - Timer job is not running

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a server farm configuration with 2 web server, 1 app servers and 1 database server.

What i am trying to do from timer job is to loop through all web applications present in the server farm and perform some action against some web-applications.

I have timer job which is provisioned with Central admin web application and locktype as ContentDatabse passed as parameter, and i have scheduled this job to run every  2 minutes. This timer job is provisioned by a feature which has a farm scope.
Central admin site is hosted on web servers but not on app server.

**My timer job never runs.**

In Central admin, i see job is scheduled to be run from 2 web servers but not from app server.

In SharePoint app server log i see one interesting log which says "Job definition TestJob, id 779b3ccf-df47-4c4d-aaea-7b3ae2f6502a has no online instance for service Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService, id db200214-6eb2-4696-bb3b-53cb12119650, ignoring"

If i stop the SharePoint timer service running in the app servers my timer job runs, after my job has run once, if i start the timer service in app server, my job runs every 2 minutes as expected. From this blog i have came to know that "So, the first thing is that for a particular server to be eligible to run the job, it must be provisioned with the service or web app associated with the job." And my app servers does not host the web applications.

My questions is.

1. Why is my timer job is trying to run from the app servers?
2. If i pass a web server while provisioning timer job is that correct? I think timer job becomes tied to particular server and removing/ taking it down may make the timer job not to run.